# Unable to display variables on handlebars through nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am trying to use Handlebars template with node.js and MongoDB.

Below is the schema declaration in user.js file:-

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    index:true
},
password: {
    type: String
},
email: {
    type: String
},
name: {
    type: String
},
personid: {
    type: String
}
```

});

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I am trying to display the values by using the following code in index.js file:-

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
User.find(function (err, docs){
    res.render('index', {
        users: docs
    });
})
```

});

I would like to know how display this in the index.handlebars file? Using HTML format is not working.

Comment: Could be almost anything.  Post your html page. Plus you need  to have a query in your find method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to archive is to render handlebars template with Express. 
For this purpose, you need to use view engine for Express module, for example, you can use this [one](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)

**Installation**

```
npm install -S express-handlebars
```

You need to have `views` folder in the root of the project.

**Using**

Just require this module with `require` and use it with your Express app.

```
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
```